# How get left position by element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need get position element in table.
But function position() returns me to the other data.

img - name elemnt. i = 0;

```
alert('0 ' + $(img + i).attr('style'));

var position = $(img + i).position();
var left = Math.round(position.left);

alert('1 left= ' + left);
alert('1 ' + $(img + i).attr('style'));
$(img + i).attr('style', 'position:absolute;display:block;left:' + left + 'px;top:' + position.top + 'px;');
alert('2 ' + $(img + i).attr('style'));
```

trace:

> 0 position:absolute;display:block;left:289px;top:0px;
>
> 1 left= 582
>
> 1 position:absolute;display:block;left:289px;top:0px;
>
> 2 position:absolute;display:block;left:582px;top:159.0833282470703px;

**update:**
html:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" id="target" cellspacing="0" width="602" height="500" style="float: left;
        margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; background: url(/content/games/kamikaze2/back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img id="stone_0" src="/content/games/kamikaze2/stone0.gif" width="31" height="28"
                        class="c" onclick="go()" >
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide some markup.

Comment: "$(img + i)" ? That's strange. What is img ?

Comment: img - this var "stone_".

Comment: use $('#'+img+i) instead of $(img + i)

Comment: I was wrong, there '# stone_ - on-screen action takes place, but there is no valid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var position = $(img + i).position();
var left = Math.round($(img + i).css("left"));
```